# ionic -java- refresh complet when 4 function complet

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

i use refresher **ionic v3** for getting new data in ionic page
but when refreshing, **4 function runs**, all those function are http request (getting api). i want when 4 functions complete then refresh complete
i try but cant solve it, please guide how do it, using async or callback or other method ?

sample 1 of 4 function :

```
getTrendSongs(){
    this.is_songs = false;
    this.api.get('songs?_embed&per_page=6')
      .subscribe((data:any) => {
        this.trendSongs = data;
        this.is_songs = true;
          this.block_load = this.block_load + 1;
        this.storage.set('trend_songs',JSON.stringify(this.trendSongs));
      }, error => {
        this.is_songs = true;
      });
  }
```

refreshing function run then 4 function (get data) execute , if those 4 function complete get data then refreshing function completes

thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Go with async operation***

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
        console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);
         //here you can perform your async operation If this done successfully then only call  
       //refresher.complete();

 }
```

for reference, you can refer this doc [Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/)

Comment: thanks, but i have 4 function that be complet then refresher complet, its for one function